# React Native BackgroundImage doesn't show required GIFs - iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, gif, react-native-ios, imagebackground

is it possible, to show animated GIFs with  - source={require(...)} on iOS with React-Native?

The following example do not work:

```
<ImageBackground source={require(...)} style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} />
```

This Example works:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/JQ3IMbDi5Jkw8/giphy.gif'}} style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} />
```

I will use ImageBackground with "require" to show an animated GIF on IOS.
Everything works on Android.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OfCourse, it will also work on IOS. You can test it by using https://snack.expo.io

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/ry6xR2vG7) is using ImageBackground component in IOS.